Pass MS Azure Auth from Keycloak to MS-Application loaded in iFrame
I am currently authenticating myself in keycloak via Microsoft.
Is it possible to "share" that session to, for example, iFrames that display a onedrive file (embedded). At the moment I need to authenticate myself for every iFrame.
Thanks in advance.
